# cursor:pointer on Highcharts Plotband or clickable Plotband Lable

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to style the cursor to pointer by hovering a Highchart-Plotband. This seems to be impossible. It is possible to turn the Cursor by hovering the Plotband-Lable to pointer. But what didn´t work, was to make the Lable clickable. Both ways would be okay for me - a clickable Label or a clickable Plotband in case it would be possible to style the cursor. Can anyone help?

```
    plotBands : [{
                                color : '#ca3123', 
                                from : 0, 
                                to : 5.5, 
                                id : 0,

                                events : {
                                    mouseover : function() {
                                    //  this.css('cursor','pointer'); doesnt´t work
                                        },
                                        mouseout : function() {

                                        },
                                    click : function(e) {
                                        alert(this.id);
                                    }
                                },
                                label : {
                                    text : 'Label-Text',
                                    verticalAlign : 'Top',
                                    textAlign : 'right',
                                    rotation : 270,
                                    zIndex : 1,
                                    x : 5,
                                    y : 15,

                                    style : {
                                        allowPointSelect : true,
                                        cursor : 'pointer',
                                        color : '#fff',
                                        fontFamily : 'Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif',
                                        fontWeight : 'bold',
                                        fontSize : '14px'
                                    }

                                }

                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
mouseover: function () {
$("body").css('cursor','pointer');
},
mouseout:function () {
$("body").css('cursor','default');
},
```

**Edited:**

- afterload function (think you can also add an id to your plotband for better access)
- Example: http://jsfiddle.net/48uL9gpe/3/

Comment: was surprised, that cannot use formatter function... 
for other labels you can use

labels: { useHTML: true, formatter: function () { return '<div class="xAxisLabel">' + this.value + '</div>'; } } and get access by class or id